# Using sed to retrieve part of a line

Tags: macos, regex, sed

I have git svn command like this:

`git svn log --limit=1 --oneline`

It will output oneline like this:

`r12345 | <anything, as it is svn comment inputted by svn-user>`

I am trying to pipe in sed command so that I get the `12345` only, however, I can't get it to work.. There are a lot of errors and the current one is `parenthesis not balanced`

my last command was as follows:

`git svn log --limit=1 --oneline | sed -e 's/r\(0-9) |*/\1/'`

I've googled and the sed documentation isn't quite clear... I am not very good with regex and my best experience is with `git --grep` which is simplified regex with good documentation.

Environment is MacOSX terminal, if matters.

EDIT:

`sed -n 's/r\(0-9*\)/\1/` works, but returns empty string.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a regex-free solution, [because](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

(take it with a grain of salt)

You can use [`cut`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cut.1.html) twice:

```
git svn log --limit=1 --oneline | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -c 2-
```

The first cut (`cut -d ' ' -f 1`) sets space as column delimiter and selects only the first column, so `r12345`. The second cut (`cut -c 2-`) selects character at position 2 and following (`2-`).

Comment: +1 for the regex-free solution and the explanation.

Comment: For what it's worth, the quote on regex kinda more applies to more complicated cases. While you certainly don't need regex for this problem, I'd encourage OP to get more familiar with it as it is utterly invaluable for text matching and extraction. I'd also consider it simpler than your solution, to be honest (of course, partly because I already know regex).

Answer (score 7):

You are nearly there

```
sed -e 's/r\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/'
```

You have to tell sed both what you want `\([0-9]*\)` and what you don't want /`r` & `.*/`

Comment: The `[0-9]*` is greedy, so I don't think that the space in the middle does anything useful.

Comment: Modern REGEX solvers look first and foremost for fixed strings to match (here `r` and space) so it might speed it up a little, depending on a solver of course.

Comment: Are we really talking about speeding up a regex on a single line of text where multiple processes are launched? :)

Answer (score 3):

I feel like `sed` isn't even the best tool here, since that's for modifying the line, but I view this more as an extraction issue. For which regex with groups is a very reasonable way to go. For whatever reason, `grep` doesn't have any way to extract groups, which I find weird. Thankfully `pcregrep` does.

```
pcregrep -o1 "^r([0-9]+)"
```

Will match the pattern "r" followed by some numbers, only at the start of the line (that's what the `^` does -- otherwise you'd possibly extract multiple matches if the commit message referred to another commit). The `-o1` is to extract the 1st group. Example:

```
$ echo "r12345 | <anything>" | pcregrep -o1 "^r([0-9]+)"
12345
```

Why use this instead of `sed`? Purely for simplicity. You only need to extract something, so can use pure regex. I view this as much simpler than the `sed` answer.

Comment: Extraction is a perfectly valid and conventional use of `sed`. Take this commonly seen format `sed -n '/foo/p'` (acts just like `grep foo`). Or `sed 10q` (same as `head -10`)  Check out http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt for many more examples.

Comment: Fair enough @BLayer. I guess more what I was going for is that while sed is extremely powerful, I view it as quite complicated. Often more powerful than one might desire for the job.

Answer (score -1):

```
An other alternative may be:

$ echo "r12345 | " | sed -n 's/^r\([0-9]*\) .*$/\1/p'
12345
$_
```

Comment: Even if it might solve the problem, please always accompany all code answers with an explanation.

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as [the first answer](https://superuser.com/q/1230847/150988#1230855).  How is it different?  Is it better in any way?

Comment: Yes, regexp is similar. But the difference is in \`-n' option passed from commandline to \`sed', and with command \`p' to print exactly what to do. Usefull in case to \`pipe' multiple lines, too.